# How to fix code in RMarkdown for simulation that will not run due to "Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale"?

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am wondering what is wrong with my following R code (R markdown)? I keep getting an error message for the last line that says "Error in h(x.n, df = N - 2) : unused argument (df = N - 2)". I am very confused because my TA looked at my code and told me that it should run perfectly.

For context, this is the problem I am working on:

[image: Problem]

```
library(MASS)
library(tidyverse)
library(hypergeo)

set.seed(1)
rm(list=ls())



N=7
Nsim=10000
rho=0
Sigma=matrix(c(1,rho,rho,1),2,2)
Sigma
mu=c(0,0)

r_vec=matrix(NaN,nrow=1,ncol=Nsim)

#have function mvrnorm-->simulate from multivariate normal distribution. N=7 Correlation matrix sigma. before X was fixed but now is random and formal dependence from Y that I can control. Compute rho hat and see if on average it gives me correct rho. Check how serious bias is when the expected value of rho hat isn't equal to rho. I want a feeling about whether this is something I should worry about or not
for (i in 1:Nsim){
  data=mvrnorm(N, mu, Sigma)
  r_vec[i]=cor(data[,1],data[,2])
}

mean(r_vec)

update.packages("deSolve")

x.n=seq(-1,1,0.1)

sim_rho0<-function(Nsim,N,rho){
  rho=rho
  mu=c(0,0)
  Sigma=matrix(c(1,rho,rho,1),nrow=2)
  r_vec=matrix(NaN,nrow=Nsim)
  
  for (i in 1:Nsim){
    data=mvrnorm(N, mu, Sigma)
    r_vec[i]=cor(data[,1],data[,2])
  }
  
  
  # here we compute t, which should have a t_{N-2} distribution. This is different here and trying to reconstruct the .Not a mathematical proof. Might be a mistake*****

   #range of values and plotting density for each one

h<- function(N,rho,x.n){
    rho=rho
    a <- ((N-2)*(gamma(N-1))*(1-rho^2)^(N-1)/2*(1-x.n^2)^(N-4)/2)/((2*pi)*(sqrt(N-1/2))((1-x.n*rho)^(N-3/2)))
    b <- hypergeo(1/2, 1/2, (2*N-1/2), ((x.n*rho)+1)/2)
    h2 = a*b
    return(h2)
    
    }
  
  
  t=r_vec*sqrt(N-2)/(1-r_vec^2)
  x.n=seq(-1,1,0.1)
  y.n= h(N=10, rho=0.8, x.n=x.n)
  
  df=tibble(X=t)
  df2=tibble(x=x.n,y=y.n)
  ggplot()+geom_histogram(data=df, aes(x=X,y=..density..),binwidth=0.2,
color="black", fill="white")+ geom_line(data = df2, aes(x = x, y = y), 
color = "red")+xlim(-5,5)
                                                                                      
}

rho=0.8
Nsim=3000
N=10
sim_rho0(Nsim,N,rho)
```

Answer (score 0):

You've defined that the function `h` has the arguments `N`, `rho` and `x.n`. Then you try to call it with the argument `df` which `h` does not have, therefore you get the error. You need to call `h` with the correct arguments (i.e. also don't leave out `N` and `rho`, and if the value `x.n` should be passed to the function argument `x.n`, you need to specify it (don't use a positional argument). I also recommend to follow a style guide, e.g. https://style.tidyverse.org/